# Unable to monitor the Security Event Log

Tags: c#, .net, windows, event-log

I have this code:

```
{
    EventLog ev = new EventLog("Security");
    ev.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(ev_EntryWritten);
}

static void ev_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    log_to_file("ev_EntryWritten");
}
```

But I receive no security events whatsoever. The program runs as a Windows Service on XP SP3. What am I missing?

Comment: Under what account is it running?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Local System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set `EnableRaisingEvents = true;`

Also, I would run it as a normal application first prior to running it under a service account. Make sure it isn't running under LocalSystem but some other user that is defined for that service as the logon user. You will not see GUI for a service so `Console.WriteLine` is useless.

Comment: I'm actually writing the line to a log file.

Comment: @lzm: Ok, either way I recommend you setup a separate user to run your service and you verify that `EnableRaisingEvents` is set to true or it will not work.

Comment: Yes, also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx

Comment: Ok. Can't I run the service under the local system account?

Comment: Yes, but it can lead to security violation or exploit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation

Comment: Thanks. I figured that besides setting the EnableRaisingEvents property I needed to enable auditing on SecPol.msc.